# Работы с DOM. React Refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

Есть следующий код компонента:

```
const Gallery = (props) => {
    const galleryRef = useRef();
    const [galleryDimensions, setGalleryDimensions] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setGalleryDimensions({
            width: galleryRef.current.offsetWidth,
            height: galleryRef.current.offsetHeight,
        });


        // Строка 1
        const ul = galleryRef.current.children;
        const ulChildren = ul[0].children;
        
        // 
        const imgs = galleryRef.current.getElementsByTagName('img');
    }, [])

    return (
        <GalleryContainer ref={galleryRef} >
            <ul>
                {
                    srcs.map((imgUrl, ind, array) => (
                        <GalleryItem key={imgUrl}>
                            <Img src={imgUrl} /> 
                        </GalleryItem>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>       
        </GalleryContainer>
    );
}
```

Html структура компонента:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Мне необходимо получить размеры последнего элемента img. Я пытаюсь сделать это через уже определённый ref на GalleryContainer в хуке useEffect.

Вопросы:
В строке 1 в useEffect я достаю ul элемент, получаю - HTMLCollection [ul]:

```
const ul = galleryRef.current.children; // HTMLCollection [ul]
```

Далее я могу обратиться к нулевому элементу ul[0]
и взять у него дочерние элементы:

```
const ulChildren = ul[0].children; // HTMLCollection []
```

Почему в этом случае я получаю пустую коллекцию? Если ее развернуть в консоле браузера, то элементы в ней все же есть:

```
    HTMLCollection []0: li.Gallery__GalleryItem-wbytoh-1.crijyy1: 
li.Gallery__GalleryItem-wbytoh-1.crijyy2: li.Gallery__GalleryItem-wbytoh-1.crijyy3: li.Gallery__GalleryItem-wbytoh-1.crijyy4: li.Gallery__GalleryItem-wbytoh-1.crijyy5: li.Gallery__GalleryItem-wbytoh-1.crijyy
```

Но почему то я не могу их достать и перебрать с помощью Array.from.

Я могу пойти другим путем, без промежуточных переборов ul:

```
const imgs = galleryRef.current.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

И получу также пустую HTMLCollection [], в которой если раскрыть, будут находиться элементы, но достать я их не могу.

Comment: Почему просто не назначить ref последней позиции массива? А не появляется, потому что html появляется позже вызова функции (хз почему, но если в консоли после разворачивания массива данные есть, то обычно в этом причина)